# Gradle java-library-distribution custom zip name and jar location in zip

Tags: gradle

I am looking at the java-library-distribution plugin and it does pretty much everything I want, however, I have some issues.

- I want to control the name of the output zip file so it becomes
  group-module-version-bin.zip instead of group-module-version.zip, I
  can control the first bit but I cannot seem to be able to add the
  bin to the generated name.
- Instead of pulling in the project jar to the top level of the generated zip I
  want to put it in the libs directory, along with the dependencies
- I want to pull in some resources but my project already exists. I
  want to try and avoid refactoring file locations at the moment. If I
  put the files in src/main/dist they come in exactly how I want them,
  but if I specify the contents in distributions -> main they are dropped into the top level of
  the zip. I tried using into on the contents -> from but this seems to
  cause everything to move into that sub directory including the libs and jars.

I suppose I could write my own zip task, but I would much sooner use an existing plugin if I can get it working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the second and third pieces with the following code. Basically I looked at the java-library-distributions code and plagarised that using the distributions plugin.

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('resources/config') {
                from { 'bin/config' }
            }
            into('resources/img') {
                from { 'bin/img' }
            }
            into('lib') {
                from(jar)
            }
            from { 'bin/xxx.bat' }
        }
    }
}
```

However my question about the output file name still stands.

Answer (score 0):

Using the baseName property, you can control the name of the output file:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            baseName = "Test-${project.getProperty('group')}-${project.getProperty('version')}-bin"
```

However, the version is always appended at the end, which gives the following result:
build/distributions/Test-group-4.4.0-SNAPSHOT-bin-4.4.0-SNAPSHOT.tar

This could work if you can move the "bin" part somewhere else in the name.

Comment: I decided to convince my colleagues to drop the bin from the name. :-)

Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

The '-bin' part on the end of the name is called a "classifier" (it's a Maven term).  You can set it in the artifacts section of your build.gradle:

`artifacts {
    yourConfigurationName distZip {
        classifier = 'bin'
    }
}`

Code 'artifacts' and 'distZip' exactly as shown.
Change 'yourConfigurationName' to the name of whatever Configuration you are putting this package into (as defined by a 'configurations { yourConfigurationName }' section of build.gradle), when uploading it to a repository.

This will produce a group-module-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip

This has been working for me for a couple of hours.  I'm publishing to Artifactory, but I think it should work with any kind of upload.